# Erro DJANGO: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured no tutorial inicial!

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Sou iniciante no Python e estou fazendo o tutorial do Django e utilizando o PyCharm como IDE. Quando executo o comando pelo console interno do PyCharm:

```
from polls.models import Question
```

ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Gostaria de uma ajuda da comunidade de como poderia resolver. Lembrando que é só no PyCharm, quando executo os comandos pelo *prompt* DOS funciona.

Comment: Grato pelas correções, sou novo na comunidade!

Comment: Olá Marley, Tudo tranquilo? Você adicionou a app "polls" no settings.py em "INSTALLED_APPS"?

Comment: Olá Victor! Sim, adicionei, ficou: 'polls.apps.PollsConfig' dentro do settings

Comment: A aplicação funciona bem, porém dentro do DOS. Quando tento usar a aplicação dentro do PyCharm, através do Console interno ele apresenta o erro.

Comment: Marley, no INSTALLED_APPS, você deve informar o caminho até o app polls, neste caso, deixe apenas "apps.polls". Sobre o PyCharm, você está usando virtualenv? Se for este o caso, você precisara informar ao PyCharm qual interpretador ele deverá utilizar, por padrão ele puxa a instalação geral do Python, mas, se você usa virtualenv, precisará informar o caminho do arquivo python.exe dentro do virtualenv.